# Переменная в коде php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код в которой участвует переменная `$_GET['id']` (выводится со временем).
Если ее нет как отключить ее функционал для того что бы не выводилась ошибка в error_log что данная переменная не идентифицирована?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92573/discussion-on-question-by-game-eagle----php).

Answer (score 0):

Добавить проверку:

```
if ( isset ($_GET['id']) && ! empty($_GET['id']) ) {
    # Работаем с этой переменной
}
```

Подробней о функциях `isset` и `empty` можно ознакомиться [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/).

Comment: а я бы посоветовал пользоваться `filter_input()`

Comment: @ArchDemon, не всегда подходит. Например кирилица. По `id`, конечно можно применить.

Comment: @doox911 тут достаточно empty(): `if (! empty($_GET['id'])) {...}`